# write to a text file that is in my site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On my local pc  I want to write to a text file that is in my site. How do I get the path in vb.net  so I don't have to hard code the path. I tried `~\test.txt` but it did not work

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\test\mysite\test.txt", True)

''What I want is My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter( getMysitePath() +  "test.txt", True)
```

Comment: Is this Winforms or ASP.NET?

Comment: Is it what you're looking for ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Server.MapPath method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), with the below example I assume `test.txt` is in the root folder of your website

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Server.MapPath("~/test.txt"), True)
```